# Show command prompt in tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, command-prompt

How do I make a program where I can run a piece of code, then show the results? So if I make my program run `python --version` it should print something like Python 3.8.3 (depends on what version you are on), but you get the point

PS: I know this has been posted before, but they don't work for me :(

Thanks!!

Comment: GL with that. It takes a lot of work to do what you are aiming for. My suggestion is to use something prebuilt like [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/CPP-IDLE/tree/main/src/terminal.pyw)

Comment: You could use os.system maybe

Comment: @above thanks, but i gave me an error: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_terminal'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here I made a very simple version of what You may want (type in `python --version` to try out):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text
import subprocess


def run(event):
    command = cmd.get('1.0', 'end').split('\n')[-2]
    if command == 'exit':
        exit()
    cmd.insert('end', f'\n{subprocess.getoutput(command)}')


root = Tk()

cmd = Text(root)
cmd.pack()

cmd.bind('<Return>', run)

root.mainloop()
```

the `subprocess.getoutput()` gets the output the cmd would give if the given command was used

EDIT (moved comment here):
there are some limitations however for example running pause will just crash tkinter and the output will be given only after command has finished running for example if You `tracert google.com` it may take a while and during that the window will be unresponsive until it completes the process and then puts it all out (maybe for that it is possible to use threads to not make the window unresponsive at least)

EDIT (28.07.2021.):
Probably better to use `subprocess.Popen` and stream data from there

Comment: @helloworld14751 there are some limitations however for example running pause will just crash tkinter and the output will be given only after command has finished running for example if You `tracert google.com` it may take a while and during that the window will be unresponsive until it completes the process and then puts it all out (maybe for that it is possible to use threads to not make the window unresponsive at least)