# Redirect intput and output to Tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have only been able to find fixes that print a set string to the text widget, however no matter how I try to use sys.stdout and other methods, I can't get a function that takes in an input and gives an output to show up in the text box.

I can give a button a function with the command parameter, but this only calls the function in the original output box in the IDE.

I also tried with

```
    def set_text(function,entry):
       entry.insert(END, function)
       return

button1 = Button(root,command=lambda:set_text(get_seed(),entry)
```

but the input prompt appears in the IDE output box and when I input value, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback:
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!frame2.!text insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"
```

Is there a similar method of having the text widget able to take display the input prompts, take in the input, and display the output?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want but does this answer your question? [Show command prompt in tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124635/show-command-prompt-in-tkinter-window), it can and should be improved but it has the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a similar method of having the text widget able to take display the input prompts, take in the input, and display the output?

No, there is no way to automatically use the text widget as stdin. You'll have to write code to detect a carriage return and then grab the data from the beginning of the prompt to the end of the line.